# Powershell SQL: The term 'Add-SqlLogin' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I'm attempting to create a user in SQL through PowerShell. This is my code:

```
Install-Module -Name SqlServer -AllowClobber
Add-SqlLogin -ServerInstance "Instance" -LoginName "testUser" -LoginType "testUser" -DefaultDatabase "master"
```

And I'm getting the error message:

```
Add-SqlLogin : The term 'Add-SqlLogin' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

But when I run `Get-Module sqlserver -ListAvailable` I get this output:

```
    Directory: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     21.1.18218 SqlServer                           {Add-RoleMember, Add-SqlAvailabilityDatabase, Add-SqlAvailabilityGro...
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there another problem? My goal is to create a user for an SQL server through PowerShell.

Comment: Does `Import-Module sqlserver` actually work?

Comment: I don't get any output when I run that command

Comment: Install-Module requires administrator privileges

Comment: If `Import-Module` gives no errors (you can `-Verbose` it to double check), then `Get-Command Add-SqlLogin` should give results.

Comment: Does `Get-Command -Module SqlServer | Where Name -eq "Add-SqlLogin"` return anything?

Comment: @Larnu that doesn't return anything

Comment: Then `Get-Module -Name SqlServer` shouldn't either. I literally just installed the `SqlSerevr` module and I have the **exact** same version (`21.1.18218`) and I can see the `Add-SqlLogin` command.

Comment: Ok, so what is the problem? How come the command isn't installing?

Comment: Might be worth uninstalling the module, `Uninstall-Module -Name SqlServer` (note, you may need to close your current Pwsh session and open another), and then installing it again. Then ensure you run `Import-Module SqlServer` after installing.

Answer (score 3):

I have the proper output from the `Get-Command -Module SqlServer | Where Name -eq "Add-SqlLogin"` command as well as the `Get-Command Add-SqlLogin` command. I uninstalled the sql module and ran the following commands:

```
Install-Module -Name SqlServer -AllowClobber
Install-Module -Name SqlServer
Import-Module SqlServer
```

Comment: Had to restart the shell